I have a query to generate sequence of dates based on a given start date. I want to run the same query for all other dates and union the results
I have table1 with startdates in a column
10/02/2023



StartDate




04/02/2023


15/03/2023



I have around 500 values in this table.
I need an extra column which will generates by adding a month to the start date till we reach current month.
The above outcome is for the first row from table1.
I need this to be repeated for all the dates in the table1 and as I have 500 such dates.
I have used the code:
Declare @start as datetime
Declare @end as   datetime
set @end = getdate()
set @start = '2023-02-04'

    ;with months (startdate,newdates)
    AS
    (
        SELECT @start,DATEADD(month,1,@start-1)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(month,1,startdate),DATEADD(month,1,newdates)
        from months
        where DATEADD(month,1,newdates)<=@end
    )
    select * from months

Expected Table



Start Date
newdates




2023-02-04 00:00:00.000
2023-03-03 00:00:00.000


2023-03-04 00:00:00.000
2023-04-03 00:00:00.000


2023-04-04 00:00:00.000
2023-05-03 00:00:00.000


2023-05-04 00:00:00.000
2023-06-03 00:00:00.000


2023-06-04 00:00:00.000
2023-07-03 00:00:00.000


2023-07-04 00:00:00.000
2023-08-03 00:00:00.000


2023-08-04 00:00:00.000
2023-09-03 00:00:00.000


2023-09-04 00:00:00.000
2023-10-03 00:00:00.000


2023-10-04 00:00:00.000
2023-11-03 00:00:00.000


2023-11-04 00:00:00.000
2023-12-03 00:00:00.000


2023-12-04 00:00:00.000
2024-01-03 00:00:00.000


2024-01-04 00:00:00.000
2024-02-03 00:00:00.000


2024-02-04 00:00:00.000
2024-03-03 00:00:00.000


2024-03-04 00:00:00.000
2024-04-03 00:00:00.000


2024-04-04 00:00:00.000
2024-05-03 00:00:00.000



The above outcome is for the first row from table1.
I need this to be repeated for all the dates in the table1 and as I have 500 such dates.

And what is not working with your current query? You seem to have the logic down. You just need to select the anchor values for the CTE from your table instead of using a single fixed value. The other thing you likely need is a way to associate the generated values to the original start date (or possibly an account number). You can do this by including an ID or a copy of the original start date in the anchor part and just copy these values unchanged through the recursive part. See this db<>fiddle.

As a side note, if you will be joining these generated date/time ranges with other data (like transactions) you might want to consider using half-open intervals with an inclusive start date/time an exclusive end date/time. The end datetime of one intervals would exactly equals the start of the next interval. You may find that date/time range comparisons and other calculations just work better this way. No need for date-truncation adjustments when performing startdate <= testdate < enddate checks. Leave the off-by-one end-date adjustment to the presentation layer (UI and reports).

Dear @ T N, thanks for your code. It has helped much appreciated. I could generate the required dates. Thanks again.

T N I don't see an option to mark your comment as answer. Your recommendation worked for me

I have reposted my comment as an answer.

You seem to have the logic down. You just need to select the anchor values for the CTE from your table instead of using a single fixed value. The other thing you likely need is a way to associate the generated values to the original start date (or possibly an account number). You can do this by including an ID or a copy of the original start date in the anchor part and just copy these values unchanged through the recursive part.
Declare @end as   datetime = getdate()

;with months (ID, OriginalStartDate, startdate, newdates) AS (
    SELECT Id, StartDate, StartDate, DATEADD(month,1,StartDate-1)
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, OriginalStartDate, DATEADD(month,1,startdate),DATEADD(month,1,newdates)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,newdates) <= @end
)
select *
from months
order by Id, startdate

Sample results:



ID
OriginalStartDate
startdate
newdates




1
2023-02-04
2023-02-04
2023-03-03


1
2023-02-04
2023-03-04
2023-04-03


1
2023-02-04
2023-04-04
2023-05-03


...
...
...
...


1
2023-02-04
2024-04-04
2024-05-03


2
2023-03-15
2023-03-15
2023-04-14


2
2023-03-15
2023-04-15
2023-05-14


2
2023-03-15
2023-05-15
2023-06-14


...
...
...
...


2
2023-03-15
2024-04-15
2024-05-14



See this db<>fiddle.

You could use a tally table, that would make the query a lot easier.
See this dbFiddle
select t1.startdate,
       dateadd(day, datepart(day, t1.startdate) - 1, min(dt.DateValue))
from   datetable dt
  left join table1 t1 on dt.DateValue >= dateadd(day, -(datepart(day, t1.startdate) - 1), t1.startdate)
where  dt.DateValue <= convert(date, getdate())                      
group by datepart(year, dt.DateValue), datepart(month, dt.DateValue),
         t1.startdate
order by 1, 2


Or use GENERATE_SERIES and DATEADD(day, value, 'SomeStartDateHere')

@Charlieface That is only available from sql server 2022, I have no clue what version the op has

You Need put your code in a Multi_Statement Function(for genrating sequence date based on given date). Then you can  call that function inside an outer Apply for all date in your main table.
    CREATE TABLE YourTable(
      Id int,
        StartDate [datetime] NULL,
        NewDate [datetime] NULL
    ) 
    
    INSERT INTO YourTable(id,StartDate,NewDate)
    VALUES
    (1,'04-02-2023',Null),
    (2,'07-03-2023',Null)

--**** Create a function for genrating sequence dates     
    CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SequenceDate]
    (
         @id as int,
         @start as datetime,
         @end as   datetime
    )
    RETURNS 
    @result TABLE 
    (
        Id_F int,
        startDate_F datetime,
        NewDate_F datetime
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        with CTE(id,Start_Date,New_Date)
        AS
        (
            SELECT @id, @start,DATEADD(month,1,@start-1)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT @id,DATEADD(month,1,Start_Date),DATEADD(month,1,New_Date)
            from CTE
            where DATEADD(month,1,New_Date)<=@end
         ) 
         INSERT INTO @result(Id_F,startDate_F,NewDate_F) 
         (select * from CTE)
        RETURN 
    END
--***********8End of function    
          with CTE 
           AS
            (
                select * from  YourTable as tbl
                outer apply
                (
                    select * from SequenceDate(tbl.id,tbl.StartDate,getdate())
                ) o
                where tbl.NewDate is null
         )
        INSERT INTO YourTable (Id,Startdate,NewDate)
         select id_F, Startdate_F,NewDate_F from  CTE


Thanks for taking out time answer this one for me. I have used the recommendation made by TN in his comment and it worked for me. I am yet to try your solution.
